# Receive email in Ruby sinatra

Tags: ruby, email, sinatra, pony

Is there some way to receive emails with Sinatra? I've seen the pages that say how to do it with RoR, but none without. I have also found out how to *send* emails with the gem Pony. Thanks!

Comment: When you say receive, do you mean receive the submission of a form to then send via Pony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [mail gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mail) ([github](https://github.com/mikel/mail)). It has send and receive capability.

Update: I forgot that there is a [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/mail-ruby) too

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) in order to send and receive emails. This gem can be used in Sinatra just as easily.